# pandas pivot_table and value_counts different results

Tags: python, pandas

So I have the following situation. I use pd.value_counts() and get, for example, the following Series:

```
A 50
B 30
C 15
D 10
```

Then I do pd.pivot_table() (to understand whether X or Y is the reason) and get a sum across columns and get the following table:

```
  X   Y  Sum
A 10  20 30
B  5  10 15
C  3   7 10
D 35  15 50
```

As you can see, the "Sum" value of the pivot_table is different to the value_counts Series. You can also notice that **the values are simply in incorrect order**. Why is that and how can I fix it?

I've checked and concluded that the pivot table provides wrong values, but I can't find the reason for that, nor a fix.

**UPDATE:** added file [dataa.csv](https://vk.com/doc165991992_495073144), here is my code:

```
dataa['class'].value_counts()

temp = dataa.pivot_table(values='ones', columns='xname', index='class', aggfunc=np.sum)
temp['sum'] = temp.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you add input data sample?

Comment: also what is your code for count `value_counts` and for `pivot_table` ?

Comment: @jezrael added file

Comment: I cannot download file, because no permission. But it seems  `dataa['class'].value_counts()` is wrong in your sample output, because not sorted values.

Comment: @jezrael my bad, reuploaded

Comment: Testing your data and working correctly, can you check edited answer?

Answer (score 1):

I try to simulate your problem and working different like your output:

```
d = {'a': ['A'] * 30 + ['B'] * 15 + ['C'] * 10 + ['D'] * 50,
     'b': ['X'] * 10 + ['Y'] * 20 + ['X'] * 5 + ['Y'] * 10 + 
          ['X'] * 3 + ['Y'] * 7 + ['X'] * 35 + ['Y'] * 15}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

```
#aggregate counts
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='a',columns='b', aggfunc='size')
print (df1)
b   X   Y
a        
A  10  20
B   5  10
C   3   7
D  35  15

#by default values are sorted from top1
s = df['a'].value_counts()
print (s)
D    50
A    30
B    15
C    10
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

Tested with your data and get correct output:

```
dataa = pd.read_csv('dataa.csv', index_col=0)
print (dataa.head())
   class  ones xname
0     10     1    x0
1      6     1    x1
2     10     1    x1
3     10     1    x0
4      4     1    x0
```

---

```
print (dataa['class'].value_counts())
7     22
10    16
9     13
8     12
4     12
5     10
6      7
2      4
1      3
3      1
Name: class, dtype: int64

#if necessary sorted index
print (dataa['class'].value_counts().sort_index())
1      3
2      4
3      1
4     12
5     10
6      7
7     22
8     12
9     13
10    16
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

---

```
temp = dataa.pivot_table(values='ones', columns='xname', index='class', aggfunc=np.sum)
temp['sum'] = temp.sum(axis=1)
print (temp)
xname   x0    x1   x2   x3   sum
class                           
1      NaN   3.0  NaN  NaN   3.0
2      2.0   2.0  NaN  NaN   4.0
3      1.0   NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0
4      4.0   8.0  NaN  NaN  12.0
5      1.0   8.0  1.0  NaN  10.0
6      NaN   5.0  1.0  1.0   7.0
7      NaN  20.0  1.0  1.0  22.0
8      NaN  11.0  1.0  NaN  12.0
9      NaN  10.0  2.0  1.0  13.0
10     4.0   9.0  2.0  1.0  16.0
```

Comment: `df1 = df.pivot_table(index='a',columns='b', aggfunc='size')` can also be the same as `df1 = pd.crosstab(df.a, df.b)` crosstabe is important in performing simple cross tabulations.